# I'm getting an error while uploading my code to an ESP8266 via an Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Executable segment sizes:

IROM   : 228624          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 

IRAM   : 26756   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 

DATA   : 1248  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

RODATA : 688   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

BSS    : 24880 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

Sketch uses 257316 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 958448 bytes.

Global variables use 26816 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 55104 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.

esptool.py v2.8

Serial port COM3

Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____.....____Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Reghunaath A A\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.2/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>

    esptool.main(cmdline)

  File "C:/Users/Reghunaath A A/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main

    esp.connect(args.before)

  File "C:/Users/Reghunaath A A/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect

    raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header

_

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I'm getting the above stated error message when I'm trying to upload code to an ESP8266 via an Arduino (I've removed the ATMEGA32 from my Arduino). Sometimes it gets uploaded without a problem (very rarely), but mostly the upload fails.

The code that I'm trying to upload:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
  // but actually the LED is on; this is because
  // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000);                      // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000);                      // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

My settings:

[image]

Also, I want to add one more thing when the message box says "Connecting........_____....._" during that time if I reset the ESP the code starts uploading.

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/esptool/issues/490 this forum mentions that "*have the DIP switches set for the ESP8266 to go into firmware upload mode*". Some answers also mention changing a driver as well as checking the port number used.

Comment: 1) Did you removed ATMEGA from Arduino board, and connected TX and RX (pins 2 and 3 from ATMega) to ESP8266 RX and TX?  2) The "Port" option is grayed, it seems that Arduino IDE is not finding the arduino board.

Comment: Ignore the port thing. I uploded the wrong thing. I'll change the picture. Also, I want to add one more thing when the message bob says "Connecting........_____....._" suring that time if i reset the esp the code starts uploading @mguima

Answer (score 1):

So, you found the solution.
*"if I reset the ESP the code start uploading"*

This behaviour of ESP8266 is absolutely normal.

If you have an Arduino board with ATmega328 chip in it, and the board is connected to the PC's USB port, and you want to upload a new code, you just click "upload" in the IDE, and so the IDE makes a connection to the onboard USB chip (ATmega16U2 in Arduino UNO), and this chip puts the ATMega in programming mode (it resets Atmega, and when ATMega powers up its bootloader waits for an upcoming programming code from serial connection)

For ESP12, ESP8266 enter the programming mode when it is started this way:

- GPIO15 - low
- GPIO0 - low
- GPIO2 - high

Those pins may differ for other implementations of ESP; Google can help you if you need. But if you is having success, of course you did put ESP in programming mode.

ESP doesn't behave as an Arduino. If you intend to program ESP8266, you had to **manually start ESP in programming mode**.

The correct order would be: 1) load the code in Arduino IDE; 2) restart ESP in programming mode; 3) Command the IDE to upload the compiled code to ESP. 4) Restart ESP out of programming mode.

You also will be sucessfull, as you said, if you restart ESP in programming mode **while IDE is still trying to connect to ESP** (before the IDE gave up and desist to contacting the chip).

After the new code is loaded in ESP's ROM, you needed to restart it again (in flash boot mode) in order to execute the software that you have just written to its ROM.